# Error adding corrupted or wrong type image to a pdf

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext

I have a problem inserting an image to PDF Document created with Itext7. The image is stored as byte[] in my DB, and it is can have corrupted bytes or be the wrong format.
This is my listing:

```
Image imageLeft;
byte[] logo = a.getLogo();
if (logo == null) {
String logoPath = this.getClass().getResource("/com/lgs/bl/resource/bl-nologo.png").getPath();
imageLeft = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(logoPath, true));
imageLeft.setFixedPosition(60, 730);
imageLeft.scaleToFit(250, 140);
try (Document document = new Document(pdfDoc)) {
   document.add(imageLeft);
...
}
```

Sometimes I have the following error:

```
com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Image format cannot be recognized.
at com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory.createImageInstance(ImageDataFactory.java:484) 
at com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory.create(ImageDataFactory.java:76)
at com.lgs.bl.web.invoices.pdf.InvoicePdfCreate.fillFieldsDoppio(InvoicePdfCreate.java:376)
```

How can I be sure to avoid the problem, can I catch some throwable ? Thanks

Comment: What keeps you from catching the `com.itextpdf.io.IOException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bruno Lowagie suggested, it was quite simple and obvius to catch the Exception, and resolve the problem. Thanks a lot.